# Scope of ScriptDB instance for Google Apps Spreadsheet Add-on

Tags: database, google-apps-script, add-on

I was wondering if anyone knew the scope of a Google Apps ScriptDB database when used within an Add-On?  The page mentions "Each script project gets a database", so would that mean that every instance of an Add-On shares the same ScriptDB instance?  Or would each Add-On instance have it's own private ScriptDB instance?  I have some concerns around my Add-On accessing a database that contains data for users other than the current user.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScriptDB we found was specific to a particular instance i.e. Doc or Sheet. Try copying a doc or sheet that has an add-on and script db, the code for the add-on is persisted but the scriptDB is not.